# Hive Case Statement Argument Type Mismatch with

Tags: date, types, hive, case, mismatch

I get the following error when I run the code below in Hive:

04:08:12  [SELECT - 0 rows, 0.096 secs]  [Code: 40000, SQL State: 42000]  Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Line 0:-1 Argument type mismatch ''2018-02-14'': The expressions after WHEN should have the same type with that after CASE: "date" is expected but "boolean" is found

```
Select
            case shipped_date
                    when shipped_date between cast ('2018-02-01' as date) and cast ('2018-02-14' as date) then 1
                    when shipped_date between cast ('2018-02-18' as date) and cast( '2018-03-03'as date) then 2
                    when shipped_date between cast ('2017-02-01' as date) and cast ('2017-02-14'as date) then 3
                    when shipped_date between cast ('2017-03-12' as date) and cast ('2017-03-25' as date) then 4
                    when shipped_date between cast('2018-04-30' as date) and cast ('2018-05-13'as date) then 5
                    when shipped_date between cast ('2018-03-27' as date) and cast('2018-04-09'as date) then 6
                    when shipped_date between cast('2017-04-28'as date) and cast ('2017-05-14'as date) then 7
                    when shipped_date between cast ('2017-03-26' as date) and cast ('2017-04-11' as date) then 

            end as test_period,department_name
            from my_table;
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick one CASE syntax, do not mix both!

`case EXPRESSION when EXPR_VALUE then OUT_VALUE`

`case when CONDITION then OUT_VALUE`

So, just remove "shipped_date" after your CASE.